# How to Find If a Multivariate Polynomial Has Any Roots

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, roots

Let's say we have a non-negative ($ \geq 0$) multivariate polynomial (specifically sum-of-squares) $P(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)$ with a degree of $4$ with a finite number of roots. Is there some efficient method to check if they have any roots? If possible, how would you find the number of solutions it has?

Example: $$(17x-15y+6z-33)^2+7x^2(x-1)^2+6(y-1)^2(y-2)^2+5z^2(z-2)^2$$ Very simple, but just an example.

Comment: It really depends on how the polynomial is described; in brief, how you know it is non-negative. Meanwhile, there is extra information, in that the gradients at the root points must be zero. Each is a local minimum

Comment: @WillJagy Added a quick example.

Comment: @DUO that may not be a good example; since it is a sum of squares it is zero if and only if each square is zero and so it is very easy to solve the problem in this case ($x=0$ and $y=1$ or $2$).

Comment: @TokenToucan Well, that's actually the type of problems I'm solving, so are there some special methods for sum of squares?

Comment: @DUO If that is the case you should include it in your question. If you know it is a sum of squares then it is straightforward to find the zeros in the way I suggested. Set each square equal to zero and you are left with some systems of equations of degree at most 2. There are standard ways to solve systems of multivariable equations, although for few enough variables and for simple enough squares it is probably doable by hand. For instance in yours a lot of the squares actually factor further, and the linear pieces are very easy to handle.

Comment: @TokenToucan Wait, how would I do that? Could you give an example? I looked into it, and found "Homotopy Continusation", which looks promising.

Comment: @DUO Was what I wrote not clear? You take your polynomial, a sum of squares, and set each square equal to zero. That gives you a system of equations that (in principle at least) you can solve. For instance, your example would become $(17x-15y+6z-33)^2 = 0, 7x^2(x-1)^2=0, 6(y-1)^2(y-2)^2=0, 5z^2(z-2)^2=0$. You can drop all of the squares since you're setting them equal to zero. For instance the last equation $5z^2(z-2)^2 = 0$ means a zero has either $z=0$ or $z=2$.

Comment: @TokenToucan No, no-- that part is clear. But how would you solve it? You could enumerate all possibilities, but that's obviously infeasible as you scale upwards. I'm asking is there's a more efficient way to solve the system?

Comment: @DUO I just told you how I would solve it: turn it into a system of equations and solve that, which is straightforward (possibly time consuming). There are a range of powerful techniques for solving multivariable systems (eg Grobner bases). Since you can get any system of degree 2 equations in this fashion, there is a limit to how much "efficiency" you can expect. The main thing in your favor is that the degree of the system of equations is very small.

Comment: If a multivariate polynomial has a finite number of zeros, then the ideal it generates is called zero-dimensional. As mentioned in other comments, there are algorithmic approaches to solving zero-dimensional ideals, e.g. via Grobner bases that translate the problem into linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$(17x−15y+6z−33)^2 + 7x^2(x-1)^2 + 6(y-1)^2(y-2)^2+5z^2(z-2)^2$

as each term is made up of perfect squares, each term must be greater than or equal to zero.

If there is a root, it must be the case that:

$17x−15y+6z−33 = 0\\
x(x-1) = 0\\
(y-1)(y-2) = 0\\
z(z-1) = 0$

The last three equations suggest that there are 8 tipples to check.
$(0,1,0),(0,2,0),(0,1,1),(0,2,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(1,2,0),(1,2,1)$

Plug each into

$17x−15y+6z=33$

This expression has no real roots.

Comment: That was my first instinct, but as we scale up the number of variables and equations, it would become infeasible. Would there be a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @DUO pretty much every problem becomes infeasible as we scale up the number of variables and equations. We have computers precisely for this reason, to solve those problems that can be approached algorithmically, when the number of variables and equations becomes too large for any human to handle.